# Undefined control sequence: \LT@save@row

Tags: tabularx

I have following document:

```
\documentclass[7pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[verbose]{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=10mm,
 right=10mm,
 top=15mm,
 bottom=15mm
 }

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{header-color}{HTML}{C0C0C0}

\begin{document}

%\noindent
\ttfamily
\chapter{Parameters List}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{150mm}|p{30mm}|}
    \hline\rowcolor{header-color}{\bfseries Name} & {\bfseries Value}\\\hline\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline\rowcolor{header-color}{\bfseries Name} & {\bfseries Value}\\\hline\hline
    \endhead

param1 & 1 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

For some reason I get an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\LT@echunk ->\crcr \LT@save@row
\cr \egroup \global \setbox \@ne \lastbox \u...
l.31 \end{tabularx}
```

What could be wrong?

Edit:
When I add a `ltablex` package I get another error:

`\errhelp \@err@`

Comment: you are using longtable syntax `\endhead` in a `tabularx`

Comment: I changed your title as you had ` tabukarx` which made it look like the undefined command  was `\ tabukarx` (which would be a type for `\tabularx`, but your issue is different)

Comment: Please clarify how your actual table should look like. Will your actual table fit onto one single page or will you need pagebreaks within the table?

Comment: The table could be longer than 1 page.

Comment: I assume you then need a combination of mid-table page breaks and flexible width `X` type columns. In that case, you probably forgot to load the `ltablex` package. As an alternative, you could also use the `xltabular` package and change `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}...` to `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}...`. If you on the other hand do not use `X` type columns, as you did in your example code, just simply use a longtable as in `\begin{longtable}{|p{150mm}|p{30mm}|}`. `tabularx` generally only makes sense if you plan on using it with at least one `X` type column.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `X` type and multi-page tables.

Comment: @Michael: But your example code does not contain any `X` type columns?